# Perl: How do I search a text file line by line to find a specific pattern?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find a string `STRING` at the beginning of each line of a text file. So far, I have:

```
open(FILEHANDLE, "sample.txt")

while(my $line = <$FILEHANDLE>){
    if($line =~ PATTERN){
       doSomething();
    }
}
```

My question is: what do I put for `PATTERN` that will make my code work? I know that `STRING` will be at the beginning of each line of the text file, and that `STRING` will be followed by whitespace. `STRING` may change so it must be in a variable and not hardcoded in.

So far, I can only think of the Python way to do this:

```
PATTERN = r"^" + re.escape(STRING) + r"\s"
if re.search(PATTERN, line):
    doSomething();
```

How do I translate this to Perl?

Also, if this is bad Perl syntax, please let me know so I can fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there, just need to know that `.` is string concatenation, not `+`. and that [quotemeta()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) does string escaping.

```
my $pat = "^".quotemeta($string)."\s" ;
while(my $line = <$FILEHANDLE>){
  if($line =~ /$pat/){
    doSomething();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! If I could trouble you for one more thing -- why are regular expressions put between slashes?

Comment: That's the default formatting in Perl, but they dont have to be like that, and indeed can be inconvenient when trying to match against directory paths.  You can use `qr` instead, see: [Regexp quote like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'sample.txt';
my $literal_string = '...';

open my $fh, '<', $file;

while (my $line = <$fh>){
    if ($line =~ /^\Q$literal_string\E/){
       doSomething();
    }
}
```